# SAGA Interpolate (cubic spline) not working

Tags: qgis, interpolation, saga, spline

I'm using QGIS ver 3.20.3 and keep getting the following error when using `Interpolate (cubic spline)` tool from Raster -  Spline Interpolation.

```
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_FGqjeq/a0cbfbd524dc4400ac56fc861242a5b9/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

My input is a point geometry with numeric data for each point. For some reason when using this tool, the output generated is a .sdat file instead of .tif. Would that be an issue?

I also tried this with version 3.16.6 but wasn't succesfull.

Comment: What exactly was the SAGA command which was run by QGIS? Did you try the same command directly within SAGA itself? Maybe the doc of the command may help you figure out how to specify the output file format. But it's hard to tell with so few information. Try to give more info when searching for help.

Comment: @swiss_knight I updated my question, thanks. What else can I add as information? I haven't tried using SAGA directly

Comment: @ale.tenorio, Welcome. `sdat` is the SAGA grid format, and it is the expected output. But it must be filled with data to be a valid grid file. The error output is a generic error and don't say much about the problem. Parameters used, complete log of the command and a test layer to reproduce the problem are required.